# How do I load 3D textures onto my 3D model in LWJGL

Tags: java, parsing, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I made a sword in Blender3D, exported it as a triangulated model .OBJ format, it also generated a .MTL file, and I used UV Mapping to create a texture for the model which I exported in .PNG format.

How can I load the sword texture onto my sword model in LWJGL?

I can only find tutorials on how to do this with cubes, my game however is not a copy-cat of MineCraft, so cubes are no use to me.

Can anyone help me out here?

**Clarification:** What is being asked here is how to take the MTL file which goes with the appropriate OBJ file, and apply the MTL material to the OBJ object, in an LWJGL environment.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @Vallentin I'm trying to do the exact same thing as this guy. I need help on loading textures onto my .OBJ 3D models in LWJGL. So far i've tried using the Slick-Util texture loader, but that (as stated in the question) only seems to work on cubes :c Idk what else to try, i'm a newbie here, really really struggling. Ready to pull my hair out now D':

Comment: @FreelanceCoder read my answer it will give you the idea of how to do it.

Comment: @Vallentin wow that's awesome!! Thanks! I'll try and work on this more c:

Comment: @SnazzyJava it may be better to ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you could create something like a `class OBJModel` and then have a `OBJModelLoader.load(final InputStream is);` which loads the *wavefront .obj file* and returns an instance of the `class OBJModel`.

Within the `class OBJModel`, you would have some array storing vertices, normals, texture coordinates, faces, materials, etc.

## Loading The Model

If you don't know what all those things inside the *.obj* file means, then you can read all about it on [Wikipedia click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

Just to give an idea how you would make the `OBJModel load()` method, here is an idea:

```
public final static OBJModel load(final InputStream is)
{
    final OBJModel model = new OBJModel();

    try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)))
    {
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.isEmpty() || (line.charAt(0) == '#'))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (line.contains("#"))
            {
                line = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('#'));
            }

            line = line.trim();

            if (line.isEmpty())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                String[] xyz = line.split(" ");

                float x = Float.parseFloat(xyz[1]);
                float y = Float.parseFloat(xyz[2]);
                float z = Float.parseFloat(xyz[3]);

                model.addVertex(x, y, z);

                continue;
            }
            else if (line.startsWith("vn "))
            {
                String[] xyz = line.split(" ");

                float x = Float.parseFloat(xyz[1]);
                float y = Float.parseFloat(xyz[2]);
                float z = Float.parseFloat(xyz[3]);

                model.addNormal(x, y, z);

                continue;
            }
            else if (line.startsWith("vt "))
            {
                String[] uv = line.split(" ");

                float u = Float.parseFloat(uv[1]);
                float v = Float.parseFloat(uv[2]);

                model.addTextureCoordinate(u, v);

                continue;
            }
            else if (line.startsWith("f "))
            {
```

As I only made this to give you an idea of how to make it you would have to complete it yourself.

## Rendering The Model

When you want to render the model, well just do as you would do regularly when you would render vertices with texture coordinates.

Blender supplies with all the correct texture coordinates, so the only thing you need to do is bind the texture before you render all the vertices with their texture coordinates.

I will recommend using `VAOs` for storing and rendering the model, though it depends on the version of OpenGL you're using. If you can't use `VAOs` then just use regular `VBOs` using the `gl*Pointer` calls, but don't use immediate mode for rendering.